# How to print 2 arrays verticallly?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to print 2 arrays vertically beside each other but I don't know how. So I want the output to look like:

```
1 2
3 4 
5 6
```

I'm working with java

```
public class a {

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    int[] array = {135};
    int [] array2 = {246};

    String string = Integer.toString(array[2]);
    int length = string.length();

    String string2 = Integer.toString(array2[2]); //The error occurs on this line
    int length2= string2.length();

    for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
    {
    System.out.println(string.charAt(i) + " "+ string2.charAt(i) );
    }

    } 
}
```

I get the error `Exception in thread "main"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at a.main(a.java:12)` on the commented line

In this I get the error `The method toString(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (String[])` on the commented line

```
public class b {

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    String[] array = new String [2];
    array[0] = "1 2 3";
    array[1] = "6 8 9";

    String string = Integer.toString(array); //Here 
    int length = string.length();

    for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
    {
    System.out.println(string.charAt(i));
    }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Closing this as it looks like a homework question/assignment.

Comment: Are they same size or different?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou don't encourage this kind of questions

Comment: No it was an example. I want to know how to it. I have tried to make a syso on each array but it doesn't print them vertically

Comment: @user4476151 so post the code you tried

Comment: @JordiCastilla Neither do I

Comment: One for loop with System.out.println(String.format("%d %d", array1[i], array2[i]));

Comment: Have uploaded my code

Comment: @user4476151 the array has only 1 element so you have to access with `array[0]`

Comment: @singhakash what about the other one with the string array?

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {135};
    int [] array2 = {246};   
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(array[0]).charAt(i)+" "+Integer.toString(array2[0]).charAt(i));
    }

}
```

At the Class a you used the index "2". But there is only one element in both arrays.